# On When And When Not To Divide By $\tan(\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The textbook I'm using has this problem involving trig equations which goes $\tan(x) \sin^2(x)=2 \tan(x)$; we're trying to solve for x. The textbook advises not to divide this problem by $\tan(x)$ (in other words not to go $\tan(x)/\tan(x) \sin^2(x)=2(\tan(x)/\tan(x))$.

I don't understand why that won't be a good idea. After all, when we try to prove trig identities (I can't remember which one), don't we also do the same thing, dividing out things like $\tan(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ in order to simplify it? Or at least in trig problems where we try to prove 2 things are equal? So why can't we do that right here?

I'm guessing it's because by dividing out $\tan(x)$ in a problem where you are supposed to find the solution of $x$, you are dividing out a potential solution/root to the problem. But then, why can you divide out things like $\tan(x)$ in a problem where we try to prove 2 things are equal, or when trying to prove a trig identity? Isn't that dividing out a potential trig relationship?

Comment: For a given $x$, $\tan(x)$ is just a number – it could be any number, ahead of time. When is dividing by a number a bad idea?

Comment: @gj255 When that number is 0? Because tan(x)/tan(x)=0/0 undefined?

Comment: @gj255 But then why, when proving trig identities and such, can you divide tan(x)/tan(x) in the process of simplifying? There's also the possibility that tan(x)/tan(x)=0/0 ?

Comment: Exactly. So you should treat the two cases $\tan(x) = 0$ and $\tan(x) \neq 0$ separately, if you want to make sure you've found all solutions.  If there is a particular trig identity you're referring to, please include it in your post.

Comment: @gj255 Okay. There isn't any particular trig identity I'm asking for. I'm just asking, in what situations is okay to divide tan(x)/tan(x)? I'm asking can you use that as method of simplification when proving trig identities and such?

Comment: @gj255 I mean in a situation like x=x(x+2), you can simplify it by turning it into 1=x+2, even though there is the possibility x=0, right? Or am I wrong?Can you not divide by x like that, or tan(x) like that, when simplifying expressions?

Comment: $1=x+2$ is equivalent to $x=-1$. But $x=x(x+2)$ is NOT equivalent to $x=-1$...... The statement $x=x(x+2)$ is equivalent to ($x=0$ OR ($x\ne  0$ AND $x=x(x+2$))) which is equivalent  to ($x=0$ OR ($1=x+2$)).

Comment: Rather than thinking about turning equations into other equations, think about "$\implies$" and "$\iff$". Use them in $every$ step, and do not omit to write them at every step. This will prevent you from becoming muddled in a morass of mysterious methods.

Comment: If $\tan(x)=0$, then it solves the equation. So find the values of $x$ that make $\tan(x)=0$. If $\tan(x)\ne 0$, then you can divide both sides by $\tan(x)$ and solve  the equation that you end up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, one should *never* divide both sides of an equation by *anything*, unless it has already been proved that that thing is never $0$. This is the case for $\tan x$ in your equation as much as it is for $x$ in the equation $x^2=x$.

The elimination of a $\tan x$ has the additional problem of changing the "domain of existence" of the equation. If anywhere in an equation some $\tan x$ appears, then the adept student should assume that the implicit hypothesis $\frac x\pi-\frac12\notin \Bbb Z$ holds throughout the whole discussion.

The first obstruction must be dealt in the usual way: just like no one ever solves $x^2=x$ by dividing both sides by $x$, but rather he just rewrites it in the equivalent form $$x^2=x\iff x^2-x=0\iff x(x-1)=0$$ and then uses the annulment of product law, you should carry everything to the left and then group the terms.

The way to go around the second obstruction is by taking note of all the domains of existence of the expressions that appear in your equation before starting to work on it. Once you've made clear that the entire discussion (solutions included) is restricted to those domains, algebraic manipulations (the correct ones) are allowed.

Comment: So that means even when proving an identity (basically one of those trig problems where you have to prove something = something else), you can't divide by say tan(x) and the like?

Comment: @EthanChan Technically, you shouldn't. Often, though, there is the implicit assumption that you'll get full score as long as you obtain an identity that holds in some interval, and even if you don't discuss the domain of validity of the manipulations you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to prove an identity and let's say on both sides you have $\tan(x)$, in something like $\tan(x) f(x)=\tan(x)g(x)$ you can use the division. That is because if $\tan(x)=0$ the identity is verified. And you want to prove that it's true for all $x$ values, not just the ones where $\tan(x)=0$. If you want to find solutions to something like the above, you have solutions when $f(x)=g(x)$, and in addition you have solutions where $\tan(x)=0$.